# How to switch Tab Control among many tab controls VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabs, switch-statement

Dear respected members,

I am using VB .NET and I have a navigation tree view control at the left menu panel.

My winforms has a few tab pages as followed:

**(Tab Control 1)**

1) Report View

- **(Tab Control 2)**

  - Executive Summary (Tab Page 3)
  - Production Summary (Tab Page 4)

2) Results View

My tree view works except in one condition:
When the user clicks:
Main View -> Result View -> Executive Summary or Production Summary -> Results View
The WinForms could not load Result View and it shows Executive Summary or Production Summary.
You can notice the Tab Page is wrong as it shows "Results View", but not "Report View".
[Snapshot of my result](http://postimg.org/image/hjapvlus5/)

Here are my codes:

```
 Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick
    If e.Node.Level = 2 Then
        TabControl2.SelectedIndex = e.Node.Index
        Dim TabName As String
        TabName = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name
        If TabName.Contains("TabPageResultsView") Then
            TabControl1.Show()
            TabPageReportView.Show()
            TabPageResultsView.Hide()
        End If
    Else
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = e.Node.Index
        Dim TabName1 As String
        TabName1 = TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name
        If TabName1.Contains("TabPage3") Or TabName1.Contains("TabPage4") Then
            TabControl2.Show()
            TabPageResultsView.Show()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Could you share some hint or guide me?

Comment: From your picture, everything seems to be fine: when you click on "Results View" you have to choose between two additional sub-tabs ("Executive Summary" and "Production Summary", the first one selected by default). The only "issue" I see is that these sub-tabs are displayed at the bottom, instead of at the top; if you want to change that, you should provide the code where the given sub-tabs are defined.

Comment: It looks to me you got the show and hide backwards when tabname contains TabPageResultsView you're showing reportview